# Why does useEffect work only after reloading the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I trying to center my block with overflow-x-scroll. But it works only after reloading the page locally. But after deployment - does not work at all. There are no errors in the console. what am I doing wrong?

```
useEffect( () => {
    document.getElementById("scroller").scrollLeft =
    document.getElementById("scroller").scrollWidth/2 - window.innerWidth/2
  }, [])
```

next.js
react

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const info = [
  "1-Lorem ipsup lorem ipsup",
  "2-Lorem ipsup lorem ipsup",
 
]

export default function LendersSlider() {
  const[state_1, setState1] = useState("hidden")
  const[state_fake_1, setFake1] = useState("visible")
  const[state_2, setState2] = useState("hidden")
  const[state_fake_2, setFake2] = useState("visible")


  const setState = (index) => {
    if (index == 1) {
      if (state_1 == "visible") {
        setState1("hidden")
        setFake1("visible")
      } else {
        setState1("visible")
        setFake1("hidden")
      }
    } else if (index == 2) {
      if (state_2 == "visible") {
        setState2("hidden")
        setFake2("visible")
      } else {
        setState2("visible")
        setFake2("hidden")
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    document.getElementById("scroller").scrollLeft =
        document.getElementById("scroller").scrollWidth/2 - window.innerWidth/2
  }, [])


  return (
<div className="overflow-x-scroll" id="scroller">
 <div className="min-w-max relative py-24 px-36">...further just a picture of svg...</div>
</div> )
}
```

Comment: The elements you are using probably not rendered when use#Effect is running. Try `useLayoutEffect` instead in this case.

Comment: @FLash useLayoutEffect - only works after reloading the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to [Window: resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event):

To center the content: `(scrollWidth - clientWidth) / 2`

```
useEffect( () => {
    function onResize() {
      document.getElementById("scroller").scrollLeft =(document.getElementById("scroller").scrollWidth - document.getElementById("scroller").clientWidth)/2 
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    onResize() //--> call it after component is rendered
    return window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
  }, []);
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? are you getting any error?

Comment: I think I'll have to abandon document and window

Comment: that's it, that there is no error :( but my scrolling picture is not centered

Comment: When you resizing nothing happens?

Comment: unfortunately no, nothing happens :( 
horizontal scrolling works only for mobile version

Comment: Try to add the JSX part to see how the elements are painted

Comment: do you want to see the entire component?

Comment: yes, it will more easy to see the problem

Comment: you can see added in the description of the question:)

Comment: or any other method how to achieve horizontal centering?http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/aH482/

Comment: I updated may answer, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fl79dw?file=src%2FApp.js, remember to listener the resize event

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect runs based on the dependency array you are providing it, so currently because it is empty it's acting like componentDidMount and runs only once. What you can do is set an event listener and keep the change you looking for (such as a window width) in the state and provide that state to the useEffect dependency array.
So in your case something like this:

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
const handleWidthChange = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);

useEffect( () => {
   window.addEventListener("resize", handleWidthChange);
   document.getElementById("scroller").scrollLeft =
   document.getElementById("scroller").scrollWidth/2 - window.innerWidth/2
   return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWidthChange) // cleanup
}, [width])
```

Comment: thanks, but ReferenceError: window is not defined :(

Comment: add the event listener inside useEffect

Comment: @lissettdm ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: @katuwa where in the code the error originates?

Comment: 30 |     window.addEventListener("resize", handleWidthChange);
31 |     document.getElementById("scroller").scrollLeft = // what needs to be here
> 32 |         document.getElementById("scroller").scrollWidth/2 - window.innerWidth/2
     |                                            ^
33 |     return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWidthChange) // cleanup
34 |   }, [width])